# usage of nested expression(el) in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, el

learning jsps. got doubt on nested expression. i create a list and map in servlet, add it to the request attributes and dispatch it to jsp. in the jsp i'm just trying to read the values.

setting attributes in servlet:

```
    List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
    someList.add("one");someList.add("two");someList.add("three");
    Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    m.put("one", 1);
    m.put("two", 2);
    m.put("three", 3);
    req.setAttribute("someList",someList);
    req.setAttribute("hmap", m);
```

jsp code:

```
<body>
    <br> list : ${someList}
    <br>
    <br> map:${hmap}
    <br />
    <br> using JSTL: ${hmap["${someList['0']}"]} is the value for key
    ${someList["0"]}
    <br />
    <br /> USING hardocded ${hmap["one"]} is the value for key one
    <br />
</body>
```

html output

```
list : [one, two, three] 

map:{two=2, one=1, three=3} 

using JSTL: is the value for key one 

USING hardocded 1 is the value for key one
```

why am i getting empty space using nested jstl: ${hmap["${someList['0']}"]}, is it the right way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
${hmap[someList["0"]]}
```

Comment: that worked.. so for the inner el no need to surround them with ${} and quotes ??

Comment: Yes, ${} should be only once.

Comment: oh ok.. since quotes was supposed to be used even if i am referring to an index like in ${list["index"]}, thought i would need quotes here also. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @balaji krishnan Try if it works without quotes like `[0]`. I did not test it.